# Set form DateTime data2 to form data1 + 1 day

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, symfony-2.2

I had had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599375/formtype-default-input-value-in-same-form) to set a Form Field DateTime (named endDate) to the Form Field DateTime (named startDate  + 24h) if no data for endDate is typed into the form) 
The solution (thanks to the answers) was this:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $task->setEndDate($form->get('startDate')->getData());
            $task->getEndDate()->modify('+1 day');
            $em->persist($task);
            $em->flush();
```

But when i modify the endDate + 1 day , the startDate is modified , too.

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Objects are always passed by reference in PHP, and so are instances of \DateTime. To fix this, clone the object instead of passing the same reference:

```
$task->setEndDate(clone $form->get('startDate')->getData());
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is what i was looking for:
$task->setEndDate(clone $form->get('startDate')->getData());